# What does this .htaccess mean?

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone interpret what this .htaccess means? Thanks!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abcdef\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://abcdef.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a redirect for URIs beginning with `www` (or any other subdomain).

The `Rewrite` says:

*If the address the browser is pointing at doesn't begin with `abcdef.com`, then drop the preceding subdomain.*

So if you point the browser at:

```
http://www.abcdef.com/homepage/
```

the server will redirect the browser to:

```
http://abcdef.com/homepage/
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server has been accessed via a domain other than abcdef.com, redirect to abcdef.com with a 301 status code (permanent) and append anything that came after it, so `mysite.com/contact.htm` or even `sub.abcdef.com/contact.htm` would become `abcdef.com/contact.htm`. Could be used on a server hosting multiple domains which should all run from a single main domain, or a site owner has renamed their domain and wants their old links to carry over to the new website.